# Delete empty array fields from MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb

I have imported a csv file containing Programme data into a MongoDB collection. One of the fields, **tags**, is empty for some of the documents. Example:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5906252136ac939ea93b4110"),
"pid" : "b00mtw7l",
"epoch_start" : ISODate("2009-02-05T08:16:00Z"),
"epoch_end" : ISODate("2009-02-12T08:16:00Z"),
"complete_title" : [
    "big and small",
    " series 1",
    " theres space for small"
],
"media_type" : "video",
"tags" : [""] //empty field, how to delete?
```

I want to delete the the empty tag fields entirely to reduce the redundancy of the data. How do I do this through the mongo shell rather than altering the csv file before importing it?

Thanks.

Comment: Do _all_ of them have empty tags like this? Or some have actual tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it with

```
db.collection.update({tags: [""]},{$unset: {tags:1}},{multi: true});
```

`{multi: true}` will remove `tags` from multiple documents, wherever applicable.

Comment: Doesn't this remove the entire document? I want to just remove the tags field when it is empty.

Comment: @sums22 sorry didn't read the question properly. Updated my answer.